# Any feedback on the monthly Sound Design Challenge now that it's done?

Tags: competition, community, feedback, skills-development

I've gotten some great feedback from people who participated in the Sound Design Challenge here, on Vimeo and on my website; but I wanted to find out if anyone watching from afar has any feedback as well. So, if you've been following what was going on, but didn't participate in this month's challenge, please let me know if you noticed anything that can be done better, that I should do more of, or maybe something I should add in the future.

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 2):

I was dissapointed I didn't have time to do it this month.  Even more so when I heard what other people had done, because for the most part I liked what I heard.

I remember looking at your site and seeing a comment from a teacher that was against you putting the time stretching and pitch shifting limitation on the challenge.  While I agreed with his arguement, I felt he was wrong in this case.  It defeated the point of it being a challenge.

I LIKED the idea of putting limits on what you can use.  It FORCES those participating to be more creative, and forces us to think a bit more on something that we might take for granted.  It's a good excersise, we may find a solution we wouldn't find otherwise.  Then we can take what we learned and apply it to our daily work.

At least thats the way I can see the challenges affecting me.  I look forward to next month.